# Capture output of Process algo and replace the initial $data string

Tags: arrays, string, powershell, parsing, output

I have a script that ignores some blocks of text, but I just don't know how to replace the ignored text into original string, so that it is deleted.

I tried creating an array vector but powershell is doing weird things with assignation, for example $array+=$_ appends more text than it should...

any help appreciated, here is my script:

```
#$path = (Get-Item -Path ".\" -Verbose).FullName
$path = split-path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
$files = Get-ChildItem "$path\test" -r # root path $PSScriptRoot

#echo $path
#echo $files
#echo $files.Count
ForEach ($file in $files){

    #echo "the value of i is" $i
    #echo $file.FullName
    #iterate through files from the current folder.
    $data = Get-Content -Path $files.FullName

    #echo "$data"

    # parse DisabledFeatures.txt file as array of strings (1 string per line of the file)
    $feature = Get-Content "$path\Disabled_Features.txt"
    echo $feature.Count   

    #[System.Collections.ArrayList]$Modifier
    $nl=[Environment]::NewLine
    #iterate for each string entry in $feature array (read from txt file)
    for($counter=0; $counter -lt $feature.Count; $counter++){
        #Start ignoring text after we've found the trigger
        $parse = $feature[$counter]
        #$Modifier.Clear()
        $data | ForEach-Object -Begin { 
            $ignore = $false; $levels = 0 
        } -Process {

            if($_ -match "^#ifdef $parse") { 
                $ignore = $true 
                #echo "start ignore"

            }if($ignore) { #Track nested groups
                if ($_ -match "^#ifdef") {  
                    $levels++ 
                    #echo "levels++"
                }elseif ($_ -match "#endif") {
                    if($levels -ge 1) { 
                        $levels--
                        #echo "levels --" 
                    }else { #If no nesting, we've hit the end of our targeted group. Stop ignoring
                        $ignore = $false 
                        #echo "end ignore"
                    }
                }
            }else {  #Append line
                $temp=$_
                $Modifier+="$temp$nl"
            }
        }
        echo $Modifier 
    }
}
```

Comment: This question is a bit unclear. Could you provide sample input and desired output?

Comment: I already found solution by writing $data = $data | ForEach-Object -Begin { .......

and then redirecting the output as:

$data | output-file "path"

Comment: Then answer your own question

Answer (score 0):

I already found solution by writing $data = $data | ForEach-Object -Begin { ....... and then redirecting the output as: $data | output-file "path"